# Can't create message with chart using stocktwits API

Tags: stocktwits

When I'm trying to create message using CURL:
(example from here: http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#messages-create-docs)

```
curl https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/messages/create.json -F access_token=<access_token> -F body="Creating a new message with a chart. \$ticker" -F chart="http://i.imgur.com/vMlZa.gif"
```

everything works correctly

But when I'm replacing chart and trying another request:

```
curl https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/messages/create.json -F access_token=<access_token> -F body="Creating a new message with a chart. \$ticker" -F chart="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tradingview/v/VA7nHUXP.png"
```

I get response:

> {"response":{"status":422},"errors":[{"message":"We couldn't recognize
>   the image format. Format must be one of: image/jpeg image/pjpeg
>   image/png image/x-png image/gif"}]}

So, I've checked 'Content-Type': Content-Type: image/png.

What else can be wrong? Why StockTwits don't works with my image?

Thanks)

Comment: Can you try without SSL (http instead of https on the chart)?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed. There was an error on our side where image URL's that used HTTPS were being blocked.